# Shadow piercing inside scss

Tags: angular, sass

I am using shadow piercing css for one of my styles. But I have color codes inside scss which I want to use in the style. Is it possible to have the shadow piercing inside a scss file?

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-selector',
styles: [
    require('./my.style.scss'),
    ':host >>> .mystyle { background-color: green }'
],
templateUrl: './my.template.html'
})
```

Comment: Please consider that `/deep/` and `>>>` are removed with Angular 4.3.0 in favor of `::ng-deep`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AFAIK `>>>` is not supported in SASS because this combinator didn't make it into the CSS standard. 
Angular has it's own implementation to emulate it's support.

<strike>AFAIR just using a space instead of `>>>` has the same effect in Angular2 with `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` (default).</strike>

Using a space doesn't seem to be equivalent to `>>>` and `/deep/` anymore.

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/cCezTQY56eyj1dmVHyKq?p=preview)

`/deep/` is equivalent to `>>>` in Angular, but only `/deep/` works well with SASS.

### update

SASS deprecated `>>>` and introduced `::ng-deep` for special Angular support (hence the `ng-` in the name).
Recent Angular 4 versions already support `::ng-deep` and also have deprecated `>>>`.

In the docs it is mentioned that `::ng-deep` is also deprecated, but this is for a different reason. When all browsers support shadow DOM with proper theming, `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` (default) will be dropped and `Native` will be become the default and `::ng-deep` will become obsolete.

### update 2

`::slotted` is now supported by all new browsers and can be used with `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::slotted

Comment: Please note that, per http://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing and the site footer, all user contributions are licensed under *cc by-sa 3.0* with *attribution required*. You should attribute Christian's answer, because you used it for your Oct 7 edit. ([meta discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340210/accepted-answer-changed-to-add-the-information-from-my-own-answer))

Comment: The information itself is not from his answer, it is from comments from Angular2 team members on GitHub issues. His answer gave the hint though that adding this information might be useful.

Comment: OK, I can see where you're coming from. Feel free to weigh in at the linked meta discussion about these two answers.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer is right in saying that this specific information is available in various forums. My concern was rather related to the fact that I just did not want my answer look like I plagiarized Günter's answer.

Answer (score 6):

Even though `>>>` and `/deep/` are supposed to be equivalent, I found out that replacing the `>>>` operator with `/deep/` works when using `.scss` files.

Answer (score 1):

`/deep/` was supported natively in browsers as a shadow DOM piercing descendant combinator, but is indeed deprecated (and removed in Chrome 63).

But, because Angular offers (and defaults to) an *emulated* shadow DOM implementation (which does not use the native shadow DOM implementation, its use of `/deep/` is unrelated to the native browser use - overloaded for its own implementation and not output in the final css. Thus, using `/deep/` in *emulated* shadow DOM style encapsulation (`encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated`) still works in all browser.

However, because the idea is to move to native encapsulation (from emulated), Angular deprecated `/deep/` in it's own emulated implementation (though it still works, and technically always could).